# Communicate two React children components with onClick functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, redux, components

Alright, I'm going to do my best to explain how my project is setup so that you can appropriately aid me on my quest to figure out how to approach this configuration.

I have a `parent component` that is a `smart component`. Through this component all my data from my store is being accessed.

```
class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
   this.props.getTips();
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-7">
            <ContentBox
              title="The Scoop"
              footerText="Submit a Story"
              showSlider
              content={<TipOfTheDay tips={this.props.tips} />}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

DashboardPage.propTypes = {
  getTips: PropTypes.func
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  tips: state.tips
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getTips: () => { dispatch(tipActions.loadTips());} ## This hits tipActions and runs the `action creator`: loadTips(). Which returns all tips from api. 
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DashboardPage);
```

As you can see, I have included two `dumb components` inside my `smart component`, `<ContentBox/>` & `<TipOfTheDay/>`. On the `dashboardPage` there are about 7 `<ContentBox/>` components, each inheriting special a title for the header/footer and also being told whether or not to display the footer through the `showSlider` boolean. Here is what `<ContentBox/>` looks like:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Footer from './ContentBoxFooter';

const ContentBox = ({title, footerText, showSlider, content}) => {
  return (
    <div style={styles.root} className="col-sm-12">
      <div style={styles.header} className="row">
        <h3 style={styles.header.title}>{title}</h3>
        <span style={styles.header.arrow} />
      </div>
      {content}
      <Footer footerText={footerText} showSlider={showSlider} />
    </div>
  );
};

ContentBox.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  footerText: PropTypes.string,
  showSlider: PropTypes.bool,
  content: PropTypes.object
};

export default ContentBox;
```

And here is the footer:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import styles from './contentBoxStyles';
import Previous from './svg/Previous';
import Next from './svg/Next';
import Add from './svg/Add'; 
import consts from '../../styles/consts';

const ContentBoxFooter = ({footerText, showSlider}) => {
  if (footerText != undefined) {
    return (
      <div style={styles.footer} className="row">
        {
          showSlider ? 
            <div> 
              <Previous fillColor={consts.orange} height="20px" width="20px"/>
              <span style={styles.bar}>|</span>
              <Next fillColor={consts.orange} width="20px" height="20px"/>
            </div> : <div style={styles.emptyArrow} />
        }
        <div style={styles.footer.link}>
          <span style={styles.footer.link.text}>{footerText}</span>
          <Add fillColor={consts.orange} height="24px" width="24px" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return(null);
  }
};

ContentBoxFooter.propTypes = {
  footerText: PropTypes.string,
  showSlider: PropTypes.bool
};

export default ContentBoxFooter;
```

Few! So here is where I need to add the `onClick` functionality. This functionality needs to be added to the `<Previous/>` & `<Next/>` component that is an SVG. What I am attempting to do is create a slider for the tips that I have pulled in. Obviously there will be `<Footer/>` components that will need the same functionality, but controlling different data other than the tips. Because I am new to `React` & `Redux`, I am not sure how I can perform this and not just do it, but do it in the 'Redux` way.

How do I get these two `svg` components that are nested within other `dumb components` that are `dumb components`, to perform onClick functions for specific data on the page? I hope this made sense. For more clarity, here is what I am doing with the `<TipOfTheDay/>` component:

```
const tipOfTheDay = ({tips}) => {
  return (
    <div style={styles.tipBody} className="row">
      {
        tips.map(function(tip, key) {
          return (
            <div key={key} className="myTips">
              <h3 style={styles.tipBody.header}>{tip.title}</h3>
              <p style={styles.tipBody.content}>{tip.content}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};

tipOfTheDay.propTypes = {
  tips: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default tipOfTheDay;
```

Thank you for anytime you spend reading/responded/assisting with this question. I am a fairly new developer and this is also new technology to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you've implemented your Next and Previous Components, but since you've using React-Redux, you can create extra Containers to wrap those components and pass in a Redux Action to them, e.g.:

```
// PreviousComponent.jsx
var Previous  React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        goToPrevious: React.PropTypes.func,
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.goToPrevious}>
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Previous;

//PreviousContainer.jsx
import ReactRedux from 'react-redux';
import Previous from './PreviousComponent';

var mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {};
};

var mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        goToPrevious: () => {
            dispatch(Actions.goToPrevious());
        },
    }
};

var PreviousContainer = ReactRedux.connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Previous);


export default PreviousContainer;
```

By adding a container wrapper directly around your component, you can connect a redux action for going to the previous image/slide/whatever directly into your React component. Then, when you want to use the action in your ContentBoxFooter, you import the PreviousContainer and place it where you want the Previous component, e.g.:

```
//ContentBoxFooter.jsx

import PreviousContainer from './PreviousContainer'

const ContentBoxFooter = ({footerText, showSlider}) => {
  if (footerText != undefined) {
    return (
      <div style={styles.footer} className="row">
        {
          showSlider ? 
            <div> 
              /*
               * Add the PreviousContainer here where before you were only using your regular Previous component.
               */
              <PreviousContainer fillColor={consts.orange} height="20px" width="20px"/>
              <span style={styles.bar}>|</span>
              <Next fillColor={consts.orange} width="20px" height="20px"/>
            </div> : <div style={styles.emptyArrow} />
        }
        <div style={styles.footer.link}>
          <span style={styles.footer.link.text}>{footerText}</span>
          <Add fillColor={consts.orange} height="24px" width="24px" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return(null);
  }
};

ContentBoxFooter.propTypes = {
  footerText: PropTypes.string,
  showSlider: PropTypes.bool
};
```

By wrapping both the Next and Previous components in containers that pass actions into them, you can connect the Redux actions directly into your components without having to pass them from the root component of your application. Also, doing this allows you to isolate where certain actions are called. Your Previous button is probably the only component that would want to call a Previous action, so by placing it in a Container wrapper around the component, you're making sure that the Previous action is only used where it is needed.

Edit:

If you have to deal with multiple actions, it is better to define them at a higher level. In this case, since the ContentBox is the common breaking point, I would define separate Previous actions for each type of content box and pass them into each ContentBox instance:

```
var DashboardApp =  React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        TipsPrevious: React.PropTypes.function,
        NewsPrevious: React.PropTypes.function,
    },

    render: function() {
        <div>
            <ContentBox
                previousAction={this.props.TipsPrevious}
                contentType='Tips'
            />
            <ContentBox
                previousAction={this.props.NewsPrevious}
                contentType='News'
            />
            ...
       </div>
    },
});
```

Pass the actions down through the child components until you reach the Previous component and then attach the action to an 'onClick' handler on the Previous component.

The idea here behind this is that you want to limit the scope of parameters to the least amount of code possible. For example, if you added a profile component showing your user information on the page, you might want to add a container around that component and pass in the User-related information/actions without passing the information to the rest of your application. By doing this, it makes it easier to focus information where it is needed. It also helps you figure out where some change/action is taking place in your code if you have to fix a bug.

In the example above, if the Dashboard component is your root component, you'll just pass the Redux Actions into through a container wrapping it. However, if your dashboard component is a nested component itself, pass the actions into it through a custom container so that the actions aren't spread to code that don't need to see it:

```
<AppRoot>
    <PageHeader/>
    <DashboardContainer />
    <PageSidebar />
    <PageFooter />
</AppRoot>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think I understand your approach but do have one question. I am using this footer with multiple `<ContentBox/>` components. So imagine, 3 footers that will all have this `slider` functionality. Will this solution work if each of these generated components need to function for different data separately? Example: One slider effects the `Tips` component, another effects...say...`News` component.

Comment: Updated my answer in response to your comment.